# Hibernate does not power down laptop

Tags: linux-mint, power-management, hibernate

I have an Asus U30J laptop with both windows 7 and Linux Mint 12 installed. 
When I try to hibernate the laptop, the following message appears on the screen and I have to push the power button to power down:

> i2c wr fail: -6

When I power up the laptop I can see that the hibernation taked place and I'm able to restore the session.

So, which is the souce of the previous commented error? and why doesn't power down the laptop?
I've been searching in google but I cannot find an useful link.

Answer (score 2):

it might be the I2C driver preventing the OS from going to hibernation (here due to write failure).
take a look at `dmesg` or other system logs as to what was going on at the time the hibernation mode was triggered.

Comment: What I should look for? I've been looking into `dmesg` and `syslog` files but I can't find any valid information. Any clue?